# My mesh looks fine in Blender, but is messed up in Unity Game

Tags: animation, mesh, export, unity

I created a mesh that looks correctly in Blender but when I import it to Unity it looks really bad.

Specifically, the mesh is a walking character (with rig and animation), which has some clothes on (t-shirt, skirt, belt).

This is how it looks in Blender: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqzhchoBxMU

To put it in Unity, I create an FBX, which I import into Unity. Once imported, Unity Animation Preview shows me the animation correctly, just as it was in Blender.

This is how it looks in Unity Animation Preview: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KI6bnOkEqEA

However, when I run this animation on an Android device (I am developing an Android game in Unity) it seems that both the clothes and the character suffer certain "deformations."

This is how it looks in my Android Device: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkIzQFUJuzQ

Can you give me any idea of ​​the error?

I think that probably it is an error with modeling in Blender, and not an error in Unity or in the export / import of FBX, since I have tried:

1) Use the .blend directly instead of exporting FBX, which give me exactly the same mistake.

2) Try a .blend that I found on internet https://free3d.com/es/modelo-3d/charlotte-aulin-95801.html, which LOOKS RIGHT on my Android device using the same Unity settings that I use on my model.

Just in case, I share screenshots of the modifiers that each object in the mesh has.

[image: Human]

[image: Shirt]

[image: Skirt]

[image: Belt]

I thank you for any help you can give me, since I have been stuck with this problem for more than a week.

Comment: No problem, I just did that :)